# Changing public key token, how to redirect assemblies?

Tags: c#

One of my customer wants to change the assembly signing policy.

Basically, all code and assemblies will be signed with the same and unique snk file.

Unfortunately, a very large code base is using the old public key token.

Is there a way to "redirect" old name to new name assembly?

I've read [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx), but it looks like it can only redirect to new version of the same assembly name/public key token.

While I can recompile code, I have a lot of aspx and ascx referencing the old name. I also have 3rd party database that serialize some objects in binary format. I can't change that easily.

Comment: It's not possible.  Instating a new "assembly signing policy" possibly gives too much credit to strong naming as a critical business process.  Especially on a web server that runs in a locked server room.

Comment: hum... that's what I feared. I don't think it's possible, but is it possible to have two assemblies with the same name in the GAC? I know I can have two with the same PKT but with different version. Is it possible to have the same version but with MKT different? Also, you can answer what you said. It's an anwser, even if it's not the one I expected.